# Adobe Analytics API

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am trying to pull segments used in different scheduled reports from Adobe Analytics. Is there any endpoint available in Adobe Analytics API which can provide me required information.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use [Segments.Get](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/segments-api/methods/r_Get.md) to retrieve segment definitions.

Comment: Hi @Crayon , I am looking for an end point that can give me list of reports along with the segments that are used in that report.

Comment: Oh, sorry. AFAIK there is no way via the API to get a list of scheduled reports. At least, none that I have found. I may be blind! You can check for yourself https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/tree/master/docs

Comment: @CrayonViolent , Thanks a lot. I have already checked it. None of the end point provide the data that I require.